# How to keep Midnight Commander running after you open a file?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, arch-linux, midnight-commander

`mc` (Midnight Commander) is an excellent CLI file manager, but I have really struggled with this problem:

How to get `mc` to keep running after you choose to open a file?

For example, when I navigate to a particular file on `mc` (say a jpeg file), and click on it, it opens the image in image viewer, but `mc` itself becomes inaccessible unless I close the image file. I would like to keep using `mc` even after I open the image file (or any file).

Similar to using the `detach` option on linux terminal (where any command after `detach` will run in the background and will not affect the current terminal session), I want to configure `mc` so that I can keep browsing through `mc` after opening a file. This is the default behavior in the `nnn` file manager, but `mc` has so many more features that I love, so I'd love to keep using it.

The important thing is I'd like this to happen for all files/extensions (not just when opening particular file types on `mc`).

My operating system is Arch Linux on i3 windows manager.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a file, Midnight-Commander looks for a match in
`~/.config/mc/mc.ext` (if it is missing, grab a copy from the installation path,
typically `/etc/mc`). Read and understand the comments and the structure of that file.

For example, mine has this entry:

```
type/image
 Open=xfimage %f &
```

A image file matches the `image` type, as `file -i filename` will show,
so `xfimage` will open with the selected file (`%f`).
**Because of the trailing `&`, Xfimage is backgrounded, i.e., MC will not block.**

Notes:

- Remember that the first match will take precedence (besides type match, there is also shell pattern and regex matches).
- Add `2>/dev/null` to the "Open" command if the command prints diagnostic
  messages that garble MC's screen.
- `%s` macro can be used instead of `%f` to pass all the marked files
  to the program. [My answer in U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/588202) shows a use-case.
- If the command is complicated enough, just write a separate script
  and use that for "Open". Also to be found on that link.